# HapiJS Routing Problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, hapi.js

I have a routes.js like this:

```
server.route({
   method: 'GET',
   path: '/marvel/universal/verify/{serial?}',
    handler: function(request, h) {
    let obj = { "test": "a" };
    Db.find('marvel', obj, 1, function(result) {

    });
        return h.response(result);
    }
});
```

and a DB module hooked to MongoDB using the official MongoDB package for node like this:

```
function find(collection, data, limit, callback) {
   mongo.db.collection(collection).findOne(data, function(err, r) {
     callback(r);
   });
}
```

Obviously I can't return the result from the anonymous function `callback` so how can I pass the result to the `h.reponse(result)`?

Comment: You can do that only if you call h.response within your callback

Comment: `h.response` isn't available in the callback because it's wrapped inside an anonymous function handler.

Comment: I think h.response would be available, have you tried it?

Comment: @CodyG.Can you give a code example of what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, HAPI allows you to return a promise, so returning the result in a promise works!

```
server.route({
   method: 'GET',
   path: '/marvel/universal/verify/{serial?}',
    handler: function(request, h) {
      let obj = { "test": "a" };
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Db.find('marvel', obj, 1, function(result) {
          resolve(h.response(result));
        });
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you return h.response(undefined) ? What is the value of result?

Comment: What is the value of h for that matter, I updated my code with what I suggest. Although I also suggest you use a node.js debugger and take a look at the variables inside of that callback and see if they're defined or not

Comment: `request` and `h` work fine when they are outside the `Db.find`... wrapper.  Once they are in that anonymous function they lose access to return data into the lexical context of `handler`.

Comment: Ah I think I see the problem now...  also yeah duh that return statement is not returning to the right place, hahahaha *smacks self*

Comment: Okay so ... apparently you can return a promise so maybe try what I've updated now?

Comment: **SHOOTS MAGIC FIREWORKS**